# push from an array of objects to a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i get a mongoose array of objects from my req.body and I want to push it to my schema

here is what I get from req.body

```
[
  { value: '6032c54220cbcb360bdc50ee', label: 'my new serv' },
  { value: '6032566c6c17ac1a983ef968', label: 'blabla' }
]
```

and here is my API that doesn't work

```
// update employee
exports.updateProfile = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        name: req.body.name,
        about: req.body.about,
        $push: { services: { $each: req.body.services } }
    }, {
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        schedule: {
            day: req.body.schedule.day,
            active: req.body.schedule.active,
            from: req.body.schedule.from,
            to: req.body.schedule.to
        }
    })

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: employee
    })
})
```

Comment: Does it actualy find the user? Try `var user = await User.findById(req.params.id)`. Also what do you mean by it doesn't work?? I also noticed you returning `data: employee` but i don't see `employee` variable being defined anywhere, did you mean `user`?

Comment: yeah because name and about work

Comment: i only need to do services

Comment: Try to add `rawResult: true` bellow `upsert: true` option and then `console.log(user)` there could be some errors. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#raw-result

Comment: no, I don't think I have any error

Comment: use req.body instead of req.body.services @GRIND

Comment: @GRIND i think no need of $each, try `$push: { services: req.body.services }`